# Count multiple repeats after event as single repeat

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

What I'm trying to do in come up with a single query that can give the percentage of repeats within 30 days of an initial event, but only count any events within 30 days as a single repeat.  Here's a sample data set for a single person:

Person        Date
══════════════
 A                3/1/14
 A                3/21/14
 A                     3/29/14
 A                     4/14/14
 A                     4/17/14

In this case, 3/21 would be the repeat event, and 3/29 wouldn't be counted as a second.  4/14 would be the start of the next window, with 4/17 being the second repeat.

To calculate the percentage of repeats here, the numerator would be the distinct count of people who had an initial event in the month and also had a subsequent event within 30 days.  The denominator is a distinct count of people with events in that month.  In the case of crossing months, the repeat is counted within the month of the initial event.

I know I could come up with something that uses a loop/cursor or temp table, but as the data set grows, it's going to take forever.  Does anyone have any thoughts on how to do this as a single query?  It's probably going to involve a couple of CTE's.  Everything I've come up with so far has failed.

Comment: To me, it is very hard to grasp what you are trying to do. What is an initial event? What is a repeat? What is a crossing month?

Comment: Think of an initial event as starting the clock.  From there, if there's another entry within 30 days, it counts as a repeat.  The catch is that if are multiple entries within 30 days, they won't count as additional repeats nor restart the clock until those 30 days are up.  Crossing a month means that for the purposes of the calculation, the month of the initial event is where you count the repeat (ie, if there were an event on 3/30 and another on 4/2, the repeat would count towards March and another initial event couldn't occur until 4/30). Let me know if you still need me to clarify further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice one...  try this:

```
create table #t (Person varchar(10), EventDate date);
insert #t (Person, EventDate)
values
('A', '3/1/14'),
('A', '3/21/14'),
('A', '3/29/14'),
('A', '4/14/14'),
('A', '4/17/14'),
('A', '8/3/14'),
('B', '3/25/14'),
('B', '4/2/14'),
('B', '4/20/14'),
('B', '6/14/14'),
('B', '8/17/14'),
('B', '8/26/14');
;WITH OrderedEvents AS (
    SELECT  Person, EventDate, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Person ORDER BY EventDate) AS Ord
    FROM    #t
)
, RepeatedEvents AS (
    SELECT  Person, EventDate, Ord, EventDate AS InitialDate
    FROM    OrderedEvents
    WHERE   Ord = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  o.Person, o.EventDate, o.Ord
            , CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, r.InitialDate, o.EventDate) > 30 THEN o.EventDate ELSE r.InitialDate END
    FROM    OrderedEvents o
            JOIN RepeatedEvents r ON o.Person = r.Person AND o.Ord = r.Ord + 1
)
, GroupedEvents AS (
    SELECT  Person, MONTH(InitialDate) AS Mth, YEAR(InitialDate) AS Yr
            , IsRepeat = CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    FROM    RepeatedEvents
    GROUP BY Person, MONTH(InitialDate), YEAR(InitialDate)
)
SELECT  Mth, Yr, CAST(SUM(IsRepeat) AS NUMERIC) / CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT person) AS NUMERIC) AS Pct
FROM    GroupedEvents 
GROUP BY Mth, Yr;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  My previous problem similar to this counted every repeat so it was much easier.  Do you have any thoughts on making it faster?  I put a clustered index on the values sorted in the row_number which helped a good amount.  My actual data has a little over 30k rows, and this query takes between 10 and 15 minutes to execute.

Comment: You're welcome.  Using a recursive CTE is what Jeff Moden called an RBAR (row by agonizing row).  It's not really a set-based operation.  That is tricky in this case, since effectively you need to scan thru every row like you are doing a running total calculation.  If you want a trick that will make this absolutely scream, check out "Quirky Update," which I am pretty sure was also one of Jeff Moden's ideas (or at least he did a lot to publicize it). I am 99% sure that technique will work for your problem and will probably run in seconds.

Comment: That recursion itself I'm fine with.  The issue was that it was executing the first CTE each time.  I was trying to come up with a way either via the TOP trick that worked in older versions of SQL Server or hints, but nothing worked.  What I did instead was make that first CTE a temp table, and then it runs in about 1 seconds as opposed to 9 minutes.  I wanted to avoid a temp table (to set this up as a view), but sometimes, such is life.

Comment: Awesome optimization, Sean.  Thanks for the follow-up.